# My camera is tilted

Tags: 3d-view, camera, 3d-cursor

[image]

My camera has a tilt to it and I'm not sure why it does. I also don't have a number pad so the number pad shortcuts wont work. Can anyone help?

Comment: On that properties menu (with the camera selected), switch the tab from "view" to "Item", you can set the rotation manually from there.

Comment: In Blender preferences, you can tell the regular keys to behave like number pad.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a preset viewpoint.Click on any preset viewpoint:

[image: preset Viewpoint selecter]

Click on any axis and your camera will snap to that location and then when you move around, the camera should be in the correct angle.
This is the same thing as using the number pad. the number pad is only the Keyboard shortcut for this.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set the normal number keys to emulate the keypad [image: Showing Location of Emulate Numpad setting]

Answer (score 1):

To straighten your camera, select your camera and press r to ratate either on the x or y axis. If it's the 3d viewport, you can use your middle mouse button or orthogrphic modes to straighten your viewport.[image]
[image]